# How to debug a NestJS app in nrwl monorep

Tags: nestjs, nrwl

I am trying to debug a NestJS app from within a nrwl monorep (Version 7.8.1).  The NestJS app is started via `ng serve api`, where `api` is the name of my NestJS app.  When I try to attach to the Node process from Webstorm for debugging, this is not possible because  Node is not started with the correct command line options (`--inspect-brk`).  What do I need to do to get Node started listening on a debug port in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about running it with the `ng server` command, but you could run `ng build api` and then run `node --inspect-brk path/to/main.js` and debug it that way. I know it is an extra step, but it would at least be a start.